# Helvetica Font from Mac to Windows

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Im currently using mac os and the font for illustrator is set to Helvetica. However, my colleague uses Windows and he doesn't have Helvetica. Will my design consisting of Helvetica font change when my colleague views it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, his computer will substitute a font for Helvetica when he views your file.

You can avoid this problem by doing one of the following:

- have your friend install Helvetica
- change your font to one both of you share
- turn your Helvetica into outlines (select the text then press command-shift-o) before sharing the file

If converting the text into outlines, make sure you Save As first, or drag a copy of the text onto the pasteboard so you have the option to edit it later. A font that has been made into outlines can't be turned back into editable text.

Comment: You state to have your friend install Helvetica. Where would one do this from?

Answer (score 1):

Your friend can try Helvetica out for free here:

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/helvetica/

[image: HELVETICA at MyFonts]

[image: Free trial run]